# How to get negative values after conditional calculation in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Hi I have following table created for my trading journal.

[image]

As you can see from the formula,

I am matching a string `Long` or `Short` based on that I am calculating the values whether I made profit or loss.

Interestingly, in **short position**, The
value should be `-4.88` i,e (`204.9*48.7804878 - 205*48.7804878`). **But somehow I am not getting the negative symbol out**. How to rectify this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use

```
=ifs(F3="Short",________,F3="Long",_________)
```

or

```
=ifs(REGEXMATCH(F3,"Short"),______,REGEXMATCH(F3,"Long"),________)
```